# Compare Two Columns Without Case Sensitivity

Tags: r, dataframe

The table below has two columns `A` and `B` which I want to compare. If `A` value doesn't match with value in `B`, then I keep the unique `ID` binding these two so track miss matches.

However problem with this approach is by default `R` is case sensitive. Is there a possible way that this particular code I can ignore case sensitivity?

**Input Data**

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "A ID  B
                   mA   100 MA
                   ab   101 ab
                   Ca   102 Ca
                   KaK  103 KAK")
```

```
A   ID  B
mA  100 MA
ab  101 ab
Ca  102 Ca
KaK 103 KAK
```

**Code To Compare**

```
output <- as.data.frame(data$ID[as.character(data$A) != as.character(data$B)])
```

**Output**

```
ID
100
103
```

Without case sensitivity the output will be empty data frame as all will match.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the variables A/B in `tolower()` within your call?

Comment: BTW: your code fails since you have different `factor`s in your frame.

Comment: @r2evans - Thank you for pointing out. I have corrected the `read.table()` example.

Comment: Chetan, I suggest you try your own code. After `data <- read.table(...)`, I run your `as.data.frame(...)` and get the error: `Error in Ops.factor(data$A, data$B) : level sets of factors are different`. The fix is easy, but please make sure that the code and data in your questions is actually what you are doing, meaning I suggest you not be creative and type different code into your question.

Comment: @r2evans - I made the edits again. Hopefully, it is correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way by changing the case of both columns to either upper (`toupper`) or lower (`tolower`). Also note the correct way to subset below. You'd also need to add `drop = FALSE` when subsetting a single column to keep dataframe structure. -

```
data[tolower(data$A) != tolower(data$B), "ID", drop = FALSE]

[1] ID
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry! I cannot comment but there are a couple of ways. Use grep and `ignore.case=TRUE` or maybe wrap within a `toupper()` or `tolower` statement.

Ok, got a laptop:

```
dat<-as.data.frame(dat)

dat[]<-lapply(dat,toupper)

#Add ! to return the opposite
> data.frame(ID=dat$ID[dat$A %in% dat$B])
   ID
1 100
2 101
3 102
4 103
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other approaches

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

my_data <- tribble(~A, ~ID, ~B,
                   'mA',   100, 'MA',
                   'ab',   101, 'ab',
                   'Ca',   102, 'Ca',
                   'KaK',  103, 'KAK',
                   'AA',   104, 'BB',
                   'cd',   105, 'cd',
                   'aa',   106, 'bb')

# returns a vector of IDs
my_data$ID[str_detect(my_data$A, regex(my_data$B, ignore_case = TRUE))]

#[1] 100 101 102 103 105

# Processing and returning a tibble
my_data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(A, regex(B, ignore_case = TRUE))) %>% 
  select(ID)

## A tibble: 5 x 1
#     ID
#  <dbl>
# 1   100
# 2   101
# 3   102
# 4   103
# 5   105
```